# Search for specific cell in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to address a specific cell of which I am not sure of neither row nor cell number. For instance, I would like to find row, which `first column contains "211001"` and column `which contains "vybr. obd."`. Then select the cell that corresponds to these: `123,00`.

Is it feasible to address the rows like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume simple table:
[image: Our table]
Let's also assume the item number you want to look up is in `B8` and the Metric to look up in `B9`.

Spreadsheets doesn't support wildcards in match statements but we can create a range that contains the extracted values with `REGEXEXTRACT`:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$D$5,
   MATCH(B8 & "", ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT($A$2:$A$5, $B$8 & "")), 0),
   MATCH(B9, $A$1:$D$1, 0))
```

In your case where the data is on the next row just add a `+ 1` to the second parameter of index.
`B8 & ""` is done because we need to coerce the field into a string without changing its representation.